# How to delete a file when the app is uninstalled?

Tags: laravel, shopify

How to delete a file into the theme when the user uninstalls the app in the Shopify store.
I have tried to delete files and delete code into an existing file when the user uninstalls my Shopify app.

Comment: why have you added laravel tag ?

Comment: Because i am used backend laravel @ManojKiranAppathurai

Comment: are you using any package

Comment: Yes, I have used addon for laravel and Shopify integration @ManojKiranAppathurai

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to delete a file. The reason is simple, Shopify has removed your API access token by the time you are made aware that they have uninstalled your App.

Better you do not litter a theme with your code. Instead, adapt to injecting content in sections and blocks using the new theme extensions. For older Apps, provide script tags for your JS, and instructions on what HTML or Liquid they might need.

Basically, injecting stuff into themes is bad news for themes in the Online Store 1.0. You cannot help it, but there is no recourse when they uninstall. You do leave a mess behind.

Comment: I just have to show the user an alert on cart page in my app using App proxy, when the user product add to cart, I still have to use the Theme App extension.